# JavaScript problems with comment system design

Tags: jquery, html

I'm building a comment system where you just start typing and a div fades in to fill your screen with a text area and a submit box.

However, I'm having a few problems that I was hoping the community could help me solve.

1. Here's my code for the fadeIn event. For some reason instead of accepting all keys between A-Z, It accepts any key. I would suspect that this (65<=e.keyCode<=90) is not the right format for this, but I don't know how to format it.

   ```
   $( document ).on( 'keydown', function ( e ) {
       if ( 65<=e.keyCode<=90) {
           $( elem ).fadeIn();
       }
   });
   ```
2. Also when the div opens I want the key they pressed to open the div to be posted in the text area. This way you could literally just start typing and everything would appear as you had intended. I figure the best way to do this is to store the key press and update the value attribute of the textarea. After that the textarea would have to become active so they don't have to click on it to type the rest.

Help with both these issues would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
if ( 65<=e.keyCode<=90) {
```

with

```
if ( 65<=e.keyCode && e.keyCode<=90) {
```

You were computing

```
if ( (65<=e.keyCode) <=90) {
```

which is always `true` as, in order to be compared, `false` is converted to `0` and `true` to `1` (and both are smaller than 90).

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of your question.

Suppose **text1** is the id of your `textarea`

```
 $("test1").val(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode));
```

will store the string character of the key you pressed in to the `textarea`

good luck